# Input Validation / Directive with a Number Model in Angular 8

Tags: html, angular, typescript, input

Acceptance criteria:

•   Type/Model = number

•   Decimal numbers

•   Two decimal places

•   Point and comma are allowed (11,00 , 12.00)

•   You should not be able to enter negative numbers

•   It should not be possible to set point and comma twice

•   The Number should look like this „ 20.21 for example“

•   All this acceptance criteria should be checked at typing into the input

**This isnt a solution for me:**

```
<input type='number' step='0.01' value='0.00' placeholder='0.00' />


 <input type="number" name="price"
           pattern="[0-9]+([\.,][0-9]+)?" step="0.01"
            title="This should be a number with up to 2 decimal places.">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current pattern is on the right track, and slightly corrected, becomes:

```
[0-9]+(?:[.,][0-9]{1,2})?
```

This matches whole numbers without any decimal components, or with a decimal component consisting of either one or two digits.

### Demo

To be clear regarding what this `pattern` attribute inside an HTML `<input>` tag actually does, it enables or disables an accompanying `<submit>` button, depending on whether or not the input text matches the pattern.  According to the HTML standard, the pattern is already surrounded by `^` and `$` anchors.  But the user is free to enter whatever text he wishes.

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer what i forgot is:

no negative numbers can be entered (-01.00)

and you should not be able to put punk and comma twice
the number should look like this at the end

= 20.02 example

Comment: The pattern I gave you, if surrounded by anchors, would not admit a negative number.  Not sure what "punk" means in this context.

Comment: My pattern already answers your question AFAIK.  If not, then please point out where it is failing.

Comment: • You should not be able to enter negative numbers
-- i can enter negative number -02.22
• It should not be possible to set point and comma twice

Comment: @DejanGuberinic did you try the demo Tim Biegeleisen linked to? The regex doesn't accept negative numbers and it's not possible to set points and commas twice

Comment: I actually tried this with a html input element, and to my surprise, it seems as if anchors doesn't work, and neither does putting `[^-]` in the beginning.

Comment: You can add `min="0"` as an attribute

Comment: The HTML 5 regex feature of `<input>` does not work the way you think.  It only _blocks_ a submit button should the input pattern fail, that is all.

Comment: Firefox actually makes the input border red if the input doesn't match the pattern, without needing to submit the form

Comment: The HTML 5 regex feature of <input> does not work the way you think. It only blocks a submit button should the input pattern fail, that is all. -

I did not know that and that's exactly my problem. I wanted to validate the user when entering the input field so that the user can not enter any wrong numbers

$ 90.00 or $ 89.23 and this number should be validate in the input at typing so that numbers like this => 321323,2323,23  cant be typed in the input.

Comment: I thought of a directive or similar. Because everything else I tried did not work like i want.

Comment: Then you need a solution, perhaps look into leveraging some of the features which Angular has (a directive is a good place to start).